# If i call the takeInput() function from outside the class using an object it runs without any problems,

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

    def pll(self,head):
        while(head!=None):
            print(head.data)
            head=head.next


    def takeInput():
        
        inl1=[]
        n=int(input("No of ekements to be added : "))
        for i in range(n):
            j=input("Enter Element : ")
            inl1.append(j)

        head=None    
        for data in inl1:
            if(data==-1):
                break
            else:
                newN=Node(data)
                if(head==None):
                    head=newN
                    temp=head
                else:
                    temp.next=newN
                    temp=temp.next

        return head.next.data
        
    head=takeInput()
```

This is a python code

in takeInput
newN=Node(data)
NameError: name 'Node' is not defined

I dont know why it gives a name error shouldnt it just call the class

Comment: The last line calls "takeInput" in the class (during the class definition). A class starts existing after the class definition is finished.

Comment: what do you want to achieve with `head=takeInput()`, is your indentation wrong? if so you don't have a Node instance to call `takeInput`

Answer (score 0):

> newN=Node(data)

This line exists in the definition of the class, but the class has not been completely generated and cannot call itself.

I've indented your code and hope it meets your design intent.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

    def pll(self,head):
        while(head!=None):
            print(head.data)
            head=head.next

def takeInput():
        
    inl1=[]
    n=int(input("No of ekements to be added : "))
    for i in range(n):
        j=input("Enter Element : ")
        inl1.append(j)

    head=None    
    for data in inl1:
        if(data==-1):
            break
        else:
            newN=Node(data)
            if(head==None):
                head=newN
                temp=head
            else:
                temp.next=newN
                temp=temp.next
                return head.next.data
head=takeInput()
```